# Error: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: SASLUsername Domain and Sender Domain Are Differnet

Tags: ssl, smtp, tls1.2, starttls

I am tying to send email using JavaMailSender. I am able to send email to my gmail account using this configuration.

```
mail:
        host: smtp.gmail.com
        port: 587
        username: xyz*****@gmail.com
        password: ***************
        protocol: smtp
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

But when I use another server with the following config I get this **error : "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 **********@gmail.com: Recipient address rejected: SASLUsername Domain and Sender Domain Are Differnet - Sender Blocked"**

```
mail:
        host: mail.xyz***xyz.com
        port: 25 (or 587)
        username: noreply@xyz***xyz.com
        password: **************
        protocol: smtp
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: false
            ssl.trust: mail.xyz***xyz.com
            sockeFactory.class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
            ssl.protocols: TLSv1
```

**When I change starttls.enable: true I get error: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints**

After I *remove sockeFactory.class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory and ssl.protocols: TLSv1* I get **Error : the-server-selected-protocol-version-tls10-is-not-accepted-by-client-preferences**

Can anyone help me out resolving  these configurational issues.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use your gmail address as a sender but mail.aaktute.com as a mail server. This server seems to allow only local senders though, i.e. ...@aaktute.com. This is a common setup to defend against sender spoofing. There is nothing you can do here except using the correct sender for the mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because Zimbra has a setting which ensures that the credentials used for sending and authentication need to be same. Please check your code to ensure that your javamail From and auth are using the same email address. This should solve the error.